# max limit set in paragraph tag with contentEditable true

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a paragraph tag, which is editable and I want to set max limit on that. After max limit, character should not be type. I tried, but not working.

```
<p id="business_title" contentEditable="true" onkeypress="limitMessage(this.id,event);">hhhhh</p>
```

jquery is:

```
function limitMessage(id,e){
        var tval = $('#'+id).val(),
            tlength = tval.length,
            set = 10,
            remain = parseInt(set - tlength);
        if (remain <= 0 && e.which !== 0 && e.charCode !== 0) {
            $('#'+id).val((tval).substring(0, tlength - 1))
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this.

```js
function limitMessage(id, e) {
  var tval = $('#' + id).html(),
    tlength = tval.length,
    set = 10,
    remain = parseInt(set - tlength);
  if (remain <= 0 && e.which !== 0 && e.charCode !== 0) {
    $('#' + id).html((tval).substring(0, set + 1));
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="business_title" contentEditable="true" onkeypress="limitMessage(this.id,event);">hhhhh</p>
```

**Explanation**

1. You were using .val instead of .html.
2. When you were inserting the string back, the cursor got reset to start of string and new char was added and a char from end of string was trimmed. To tackle this, I added e.preventDefault to stop the char from getting added.

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your answer to help others understand how you solve the problem.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined
    at HTMLHeadingElement.onkeypress

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the jQuery CDN and you're using `p` instead of `input`, then you need to use `html()` instead of `val()` because the `p` element doesn't expect value.

And you don't need to write `$(this).val((tval).substring(0, tlength - 1))` because it will return to the begining of the sentence, so just use a `preventDefault()` to stop writing.

Try this :

```js
function limitMessage(id, e) {
  var tval = $('#' + id).html(),
    tlength = tval.length,
    set = 10,
    remain = parseInt(set - tlength);
  if (remain <= 0 && e.which !== 0 && e.charCode !== 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="business_title" contentEditable="true" onkeypress="limitMessage(this.id,event);">hello</p>
```

Comment: @Vinod Ok I think I found, I just updated my answer, can you try it please ?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined
    at HTMLHeadingElement.onkeypress